# Is a reference on T a subtype of T?

Tags: type-theory, type-systems

If I take the book *Practical Foundations for Programming Languages* by Robert Harper, the following definition is given for subtyping:

> A subtype relation is a pre-order on types that validates the subsumption principle: if $\tau'$ is a subtype of $\tau$, then a value of type $\tau'$ may be provided when a value of type $\tau$ is required.

I was wondering whether we can say that a reference on $T$, denoted by $\text{Ref }T$ is a subtype of $T$. If not, why?

Comment: This is not research level, but the answer is no because this doesn't satisfy the Liskov substitution principle.

Comment: @xuq01 Could you provide an example of that as an answer?

Comment: I don't really want to right now, because I think this question is off topic here, but I think it could be migrated to CS.SE. If the admins do that I will add an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, `Ref T` is not a subtype of `T`. In typical sub-typing rules, a term of type `Ref T` is not substitutable for a term of type `T`. A `Ref T` has the value of a pointer to a location in memory of an `T`, whereas `T` has the value of an `T`. More concretely, in ML-based languages, in order to pass the value from a `Ref T` to a function that takes the enclosed type `T`, you need to dereference the argument first. Typically that will involve using a unary operator like !.

So, while it is possible that a coercion could make the `Ref T` appear to be a subtype, I think it's better to think of `Ref` as a container type, rather than a more specific kind of `T`.

An example from OCaml:

```
# let t = ref 2 ;;
val t : int ref = {contents = 2}
# let q : int = t ;;
Error: This expression has type int ref
       but an expression was expected of type int
# let r : int = !t ;;
val r : int = 2
```

A possible workaround for this would be to look into some form of implicit coercions, which are available in certain languages. See more on coercion [here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Introduction_to_Programming_Languages/Coercion).